# How to resolved ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified..?

Tags: oracle-spatial

When application try to connect to an Oracle Service via Oracle Networking SQL*Net, it looks up the connect data for the service. When this lookup fails, Oracle client show an error message ORA-12154.

Comment: You have a tag for Oracle Spatial but make no mention of how that is relevant to what looks like a pure Oracle DBMS issue that I think would be better researched/asked at the [dba.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The solution may depend on what you were trying to do when you got this error

Firstly, you have to make sure that the TNSNAMES.ORA file exists in the correct directory and is accessible.

> %ORACLE_HOME% /network/admin/

Then, you have to make sure that the syntax of TNSNAMES.ORA file is correct.

For example, if there are unmatched brackets in the file (ie: open bracket without the corresponding close bracket), the file will be rendered unusable.

```
XE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TESTING.COM)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)
```

or [Oracle](https://cbseneet2019.co.in/ORA-12154-tns-could-not-resolve/) stuff